# Please help me to increase the speed of node in swift (Sprite Kit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, physics

Please help me to increase the speed of node in swift. I am using spritekit. I am designing one screen 2d game. in my game, there is one obstacle to defend a node from balls. player controls the obstacle  with swiping. and there are 4 more balls moving randomly on the screen. I need to increase speed of balls every 10 points but i couldn't do that. please help me i am new on swift and spritekit.

here is a little part of my code

```
 override init(size: CGSize)
    {
        super.init(size: size)

        ball1.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(CGFloat(ballSpeed), CGFloat(ballSpeed)))
        ball2.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(CGFloat(ballSpeed), CGFloat(ballSpeed)))
        ball3.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(CGFloat(ballSpeed), CGFloat(ballSpeed)))
        ball4.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(CGFloat(ballSpeed), CGFloat(ballSpeed)))

}
```

I cant change the value of ballSpeed variable after the game has started.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a score variable. You can let a function check the score and add to the `ballSpeed` every 10 points. This can either be done inside of the `update function` or with an `SKAction` that checks every period of time.

```
if self.score % 10 == 0 {
            self.ballSpeed++
}
```

This will increase your `ballSpeed` by one every ten points.

Comment: i did same thing in update function . and ballSpeed variable is global but nothing changes.

Comment: You probably have to write the line to apply the impulse to each ball over again. That way it will apply the new speed to the impulse.

Comment: Make sure that the `ballSpeed` is inside of the class but outside of any function and that it's specified as `var` and not `let`.